# Icecast intro files causing many connections

Tags: icecast

Running Icecast 2.4.99.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 just file and successfully added an intro file after playing around with the format. The file was playing but no live stream after, but live stream played fine without the intro file. I read another post about making sure the format matched, it still didn't work after matching the `darkice` mounted stream of 96 bit rate, only after formatting as 128 bit rate with 2 channels (stereo) it worked!

However, that was yesterday while traffic low, once traffic picked up this morning, I started getting alerts of over 1000 connections with historically below 500. The Icecast service crashed and it wasn't until I disabled the intro files for the 4 streams before Icecast became stable again returning to norms. Below is the Icecast mount we get far more traffic on and showed some clients with 80-100 connections with intros enabled. The number of connections would continue to increase until Icecast finally gave up. I thought about reducing the `max-listeners` below but the issue appears to cause too many connections. I wanted to post here to see if someone had a suggestion to try during our next slow time. From the `icecast.xml` file:

```
<mount>
    <mount-name>/high_quality</mount-name>
    <max-listeners>3000</max-listeners>
    <intro>high_quality.mp3</intro>
</mount>
```

And the `darkice.cfg` configuration:

```
[icecast2-0]
bitrateMode     = cbr
format          = mp3
bitrate         = 96
server          = localhost
port            = 8880
password        = <changeme>
mountPoint      = high_quality
name            = Our station
description     = Station description
url             = high_quality
genre           = Eclectic
public          = yes
```

File permissions for mp3 file:

```
user@stream:~/StationIDs$ sudo ls -lah /usr/share/icecast2/web/high_quality.mp3
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 138K Nov 14 17:20 /usr/share/icecast2/web/high_quality.mp3
```

I have read the format needs to match and you see above `darckice.cfg` using 96 bit rate. Using `lame` to encode from `wav` format:

```
user@stream:~/src$ mediainfo /usr/share/icecast2/web/high_quality.mp3
General
Complete name                            : /usr/share/icecast2/web/high_quality.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 138 KiB
Duration                                 : 8s 777ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
Overall bit rate                         : 128 Kbps
Writing library                          : LAME3.99r

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Mode                                     : Joint stereo
Mode extension                           : MS Stereo
Duration                                 : 8s 803ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 137 KiB (100%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.99r
Encoding settings                        : -m j -V 4 -q 3 -lowpass 17 -b 128
```

Again, I was not able to get the stream to play following the intro until I used 128 bit rate file. Perhaps the `darkice.cfg` needs to match or someone knows another reason the large number of connections are happening when using intros?

It has come to my attention that Icecst2 2.4.99 is beta and not to be used for production. I installed from source and will try a `make uninstall` and install version `2.4.2` found in the Ubuntu repository.